# Where is source for EF 6.1.3?

Tags: entity-framework, open-source

According to nuget [Entity Framework is in version `6.1.3`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/). I've cloned the [repository on codeplex](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) but don't see any corresponding code

```
W:\entityframework> git tag
6.0.0
6.0.0-beta1
6.0.0-rc1
6.0.1
6.0.2
6.0.2-beta1
6.1.0
6.1.0-alpha1
6.1.0-beta1
6.1.1
6.1.1-VS14
6.1.1-beta1
```

So...where's the source?

**Edit:** For that matter, where is 6.0.1 - I can update to that tag but running `.\Build.cmd` (and ignoring the fact that the tests fail to start) produces an assembly that is tagged as 6.0.0 and with methods that do not match a stack trace my application error reports.

Comment: Does `git ls-remote --tags` show the rest of the tags?

Comment: Oh duh...my origin is a fork... Still am confused about the versioning stuff though

Answer (score 2):

Using `git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/entityframework` my list of tags is

```
6.0.0
6.0.0-beta1
6.0.0-rc1
6.0.1
6.0.2
6.0.2-beta1
6.1.0
6.1.0-alpha1
6.1.0-beta1
6.1.1
6.1.1-VS14
6.1.1-beta1
6.1.2
6.1.2-beta1
6.1.2-beta2
6.1.3
6.1.3-beta1
6.1.3-rc1-NeverReleased
```

Checking out 6.1.3 then Building in VS2015 or via `Build.cmd` compiles an assembly with metadata 6.1.0-alpha1.

[EF 7.0](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework) is much easier, but I'm not sure why EF 6 has these build issues.

Comment: huh...I...don't get it. I am doing a `git fetch --tags` and it still shows that exact same list

Comment: Have you tried literally git clone then next line git tag?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets there is a tagged commit at http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/74b099945216aad2baf0d3017e3786c4724eaf92

Comment: I...see. I'm not sure why I'm not seeing any of this. I tried `git fetch --tags` and everything. Any idea what is going on with the assembly versioning? The base issue is that I'm getting weird errors form the guts of EF and can't find the corresponding version in source control to point the debugger at